# Mixing PSQL and ElasticSearch ORMs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, elasticsearch

I have a photo sharing app with the following simplified model structure

- `User: has_many :photos`
- `Photo: has_many :tags`
- `Tag`

Assume that this app is operating at a high scale, with at least 10-20 million photo records (which means at least ~50 million tags, since there are multiple tags per photo).

I want to use elasticsearch to make the tags more quickly searchable. Right now finding all tags like `"favorite"` requires a row scan on several million rows in my PSQL database.

I've seen a few examples of Rails integrating with ElasticSearch, and they all seem to follow the pattern of saving a record in the PSQL DB **and** saving a copy of the model data to elasticsearch. That seems redundant to me as I have no real need to store them in PSQL, and they only exist to be searched.

1. Is it possible (or is it a good idea) to eliminate the `Tag` model and store all that info in elasticsearch instead? If so, how would I join the data? I assume I'd have to write some custom logic on my `Photo` model that queries all `tags` in elasticsearch `where(id: @photo.id)`
2. Is there a good ORM for elasticsearch that plays nicely with ActiveRecord, and would perhaps help in implementing #1 above? I'm imagining using a different ORM for my `Photo` and `Tag` models since they're stored in different databases.

Any other thoughts on the best way to approach this design are welcome too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Officially, the ES folks don't recommend to use Elasticsearch as a primary database, as it's not meant as a data store in the first place. That being said, nothing prevents you from doing it, but you won't be allowed to blame ES if you lose data.

Another question you need to ask yourself is how to rebuild your ES index in case something goes wrong (and it will!!). If you don't keep your tags in PSQL you won't be able to rebuild them in case your ES data gets corrupted for whatever reason (ES bug, Lucene bug, HDD/SDD failure, etc)

For your use case, I would consider [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) as a potential solution forward.

Comment: Did this help, do you need more info?